# Android: Unexplained log errors

Tags: java, android, logcat

I am getting these errors in log cat every time I touch the screen while on my app. The app is responding normally, and I can't understand the errors. They are all pretty much the same, here is an example:

10-23 14:25:48.865: E/ViewRoot exit(22232): Dispatching touchevent to com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2ff9a688

Could anybody explain it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe this is just a touche event notification, what makes you think it is an error?

Comment: It's red and it's level is 'E'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that you are touching some view of yours. When that happens the `onTouchEvent()` method is called.

My thought is that you are not overriding that method, therefore the system launches that error to the Log to inform you of that. There is nothing wrong with that, so if the view is behaving normally, I wouldn't be worried.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)'s some information on InputEvents

Answer (score 1):

I do meet a lot of that errors in my project, I agree with the first answer. I did't override some method or some kinds of touchment in u view. mostly u don't need to worry about those runtime errors.